# How to read multiple large files (400~mb) change to custom format and write to a single file

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I'm currently writing a application that takes data from multiple input files each being 400 mb in size and transforming data into a custom format as required by other applications and writing it into a single file. I am expecting the output file to be around 10 GB in size after the process. How can I do this efficiently without overflowing memory using JAVA and Spring?

For this process, it is just a transformation into custom format, so it is better if not much memory is used to store the entire files. Also, is it possible to append into output file in java without having the file in memory since it is bound to be around 10 GB in size total.

Edit: added more information

Comment: Could we get more details in general. Do you have to hold the whole input file in memory to parse it? could you just transform it line by line or section by section? What are these data formats like?

Comment: You could probably parse each input file and store its data in a temporary database then read from that database to generate your output file.

Comment: @xtratic added more information. the input data format is csv and output is into a custom delimiter separated flat file format specific to the system using this data

Comment: Then just read one line at a time and write a line. Don't hold it all in memory.

Comment: I'd probably use `awk` from linux command line to do this with little overhead.